# Page reloading back to login page after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a main page for my website but before that I have also made an index.html page that redirects to my html page through login panel.

The problem I am facing is that after logging in the main page when I refresh it goes back to the login page which it shouldn't.

Can anybody help me how can I overcome this problem?
Following is my html code for index.html:-

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <title>Index</title>
       <frameset cols="100%">
       <frame src="login.html">
       <frame src="index1.html"></frameset><noframes></noframes>
   </head>
```

Comment: What made you decide to use frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an actual redirect like so:

**index1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    window.location = 'login.html';
</script>
```

If you set this as the only line in your `index1.html` you'd get an immidiate and actual URL redirect to your login page. Once there, proceed as usual.

Comment: is a function required for it?

Comment: You don't need to add anything else, it's a simple `javascript` command that changes your current URL to that of your actual login page.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be obvious that it's inside a `script` tag. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes I've used it but thats not working on firefox but on chrome and IE

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 26.0. Try to use a complete path like '/login.html'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do the redirect after the login inside the frame while the actual page stays the same? try not using frames at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you navigate inside the frame that contains the login.html, your main url will not change and you'll have index.html in your navigation bar.

So if you refresh (F5 or hitting the refresh button) you will refresh the index.html page, and you will be back to your login page.